# When seeking,silverlight for windowsphone8 is mosaic

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, mp4, mediaelement.js

When I open the source, `MediaElement` touches off `MediaElement_MediaOpened` event, then I give a value to `MediaElement.Position`, to touch off the function of `SeekAsync`.

But when after seeking, the video will mosaic several frames.
But when `MediaElemnet` is playing video, I seek the Video, it works well.

What is the problem? If the video is `flv`,there is no problem. If the video is `mp4`, the problem will appear.